# Usar um component dentro de um Shell Console no CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

Alguém sabe me dizer como usar um component que criei no cakephp dentro de um script de console do cake?

Já tentei usar App::import mas não consegui.

Por exemplo em um controller normal eu consigo usar meu component da seguinte maneira:

```
public $components = array('MeuComponent');
```

Mas no Shell isso não funciona =/

Alguém sabe me dizer como usar MeuComponent dentro de um Shell do CakePHP?

Answer (score 2):

Acabei achando a solução [**aqui**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10880694/using-a-plugin-component-from-shell-class-in-cakephp-2-0-2)

Antes da sua *class Shell* adicione

```
App::uses('ComponentCollection', 'Controller');
App::uses('MeuComponentComponent', 'Controller/Component');

class WorkerShell extends AppShell {
    public function main(){
       $Collection = new ComponentCollection();
       $obj = new MeuComponentComponent($Collection);
    }
}
```

Pronto, já pode usar seu component dentro dos scripts Shell.